# What type of group is this algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am trying to figure out, what type of group this algebra is

$\langle${5}, $\circ\rangle$ with $\circ$ : {5}$^2$ $\rightarrow$ {5}    arbitrary

Comment: You have a set with a single element: $5$, and an internal, binary operarion $\circ$. The only possibility is that $5\circ5=5$. Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The table of the operator is really simple:
$$5\circ 5=5$$

Associative: yes.
Commutative: yes.
Identity element: yes.
Inverse element: yes.

So it is an abelian group. A group with a single element is called a trivial group.

Answer (score 2):

A trivial group? You already know the underlying set, so all that is left to define is the binary operatior $\circ:\{5\}\times \{5\}\rightarrow \{5\}$. Clearly the only way to do so is $\circ(5,5)=5$.